# App Engine with Java: Deferred tasks ignoring retry limit

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task-queue

I have a cron job that starts a deferred task that runs in a seperate queue. I have set this queue's retry limit to 1. Since this task uses a lot of datastore calls I do not want it to keep retrying if a failure occurs.

The deferred task seems to keep on retrying though, regardless of the fact that my queue.yaml is defined as follows:

```
queue:
- name: stopretrying   
rate: 35/s   
max_concurrent_requests: 2           
retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 1
    task_age_limit: 1d
```

Can anyone explain this rebellious behaviour?

Thanks and good day

Comment: Have you confirmed that it's retrying an not being re-scheduled by a handler (cron).  Do you name tasks ?

Comment: My cron runs once every 24 hours. I do not name the task as this task is the only one used by the queue. I am sure it is retrying as that's what it says in the task queue overview on the app engine's console.

Comment: If the problem persists in the event the taskqueue really is retyring tasks, then naming tasks when scheduling them means you will get a TaskAlreadyExistsError  if it is already in the queue and not run or TombstonedTaskError if it has already run and is rescheduled (ie as a result of an error).  You could for instance give the task a name that is unique (to the 24 hour period).

Comment: Renaming the task does not fix things. Could it be that I need to use the xml format instead of yaml for java? It seems unlikely since the queue does get made (implying that the file gets parsed correctly, as the settings all match)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in App Engine related to retry limit set to zero. That setting was ignored, and task was retried several times. That issue was fixed in [1.9.25](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/release-notes). If you see this issue with retry limit set to 1, you may need to report it as a new bug.

Comment: I have tried setting it to 1, the problem persists. I cannot see if the retry rate was set correctly in the console but the yaml file can hardly be incorrect.

Comment: Try setting retry parameter on the task itself instead of setting it for a queue.

Comment: This has solved it! Strange that if I do not set the retry policy, it does not default to the queue's settings though.

Answer (score 0):

The task queue will retry until both of the limits, retries and age, are reached.

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/queue?hl=en#Queue_Definitions) do explain this.